# Moving Average Filter's Magnitude Response

Tags: matlab, filter-design, lowpass-filter, moving-average

I am working on filtering of data using the Moving average filter in MATLAB.

My data is recorded temperature values on the Y-axis and Time(in seconds) on the X-axis

(I'm getting the **magnitude response** curve of the Moving average filter as attached)

[image]

The shape of the curve seems fair for the moving average filter, according to the theory but,

I want to ask, why am I getting all the magnitude value for MA filter positive? (is this correct?)

Implementing other filters like Butterworth etc. on the same data gives the magnitude values to be negative (image attached)

[image]

Here is my MATLAB Code for MA (if it helps)

```
%T.Temp is table column containing Temperature values in double format.

MovAvg = dsp.MovingAverage(5)

movAvgOut = MovAvg(T.Temp)

fvtool(movAvgOut)

%Gives output the first image I attached
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Ps - DSP is not my field. This work is part of a bigger project i'm involved in, and need some help. Please bear with me if I sound irrational.

Comment: What are your coefficients? All ones?

Comment: Just shift your vertical scale.  They are not based the same.

Comment: @jojek I have implemented MA using the sliding window, and as per the documentation, in this - all values are given equal importance/weightage. So, Yes, I guess all coefficients are 1.

Comment: @CedronDawg Do have any insight on how I can shift the vertical scale?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use MATLAB at all.  Log scales are for ratios.  One is at zero, right, and both your graphs should be one at the far left.  It looks like you should be able to divide your data by 1000000 = 10^6 which is 60 on a dB scale.

Comment: @CedronDawg Alright, thank you. I'll try.  (I also started using it just now for a project :/ )

Comment: You're welcome.  Be aware that array indexing starts at one.  Principle reason I don't use it.  Makes sense for "Math Matrices", but not DSP and other linear algebra applications.

Comment: Well, you are using `fvtool` for visualizing spectrum of your data, not the actual filter. If you want to visualize things the way you want, use `fft` routine, scale the output with 0 dB being a particular value that you want and plot it. Values of temperature are much higher than 1, so it's normal you get levels higher than 0 dB. (Not sure what would be the meaning of 0 dB for temperature anyway...). Alternatively do this trick. In `fvtool` click *Analysis*, *Analysis parameters* and tick *Normalize amplitude to 1 (0 dB)*. This will normalize the values so that maximum is always 0 d.

Comment: @jojek I tried what you suggested (with 'Analysis parameters'). This works great when the plot is viewed in 'Magnitude response(dB)' but shifts back to original scale when viewed in 'Magnitude response estimate' and 'Normalize amplitude to 1 (0 dB)' is unavailable when viewed in this mode. In Magnitude response(dB) i'm getting a dense looking plot but with Magnitude response estimate i'm getting a single line which i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A true moving average would have unity gain coefficients but also be divided by the total number of samples (as per the definition of average). This is trivial since it is just a scaling factor, but if the OP divides the output of the moving average by the total number of samples in the filter then the magnitude response will be normalized to 0 on a dB scale, with all other magnitude values given in negative dB.